# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not working in PDO

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO b (id, website...) 
VALUES (:id, :website...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  
website=:website ...
```

I have a MYSQL QUERY, I have SET id unique, why

```
website=:website ...
```

is not working, when I change to `website="whatever"` it works. anyone know why?

```
$job_B->bindValue(':website', $website, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: [From PDO docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php): _You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement._  (this is probably the one and only thing I don't like about PDO)

Comment: That means you must rename the second `:website` to a different placeholder, and call `bindValue()` _twice_, once for each of the placeholders, even though they'll hold the same value.

Comment: so i have to bind another value again?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Annoying, but correct.

Comment: ha thx a lot, please put in answer so i can tick u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have run into an unfortunate and misleading behavior of PDO's named parameters in a prepared statement. Despite assigning names, you cannot actually use a parameter more than once, [as mentioned in the `prepare()` documentation:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). **You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement**. You cannot bind multiple values to a single named parameter in, for example, the IN() clause of an SQL statement.

This means you'll need to bind the parameter twice, with two different names, and consequently two different `bindValue()` calls:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
  INSERT INTO b (id, website...) 
  VALUES (:id, :website_insert...)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  
    website=:website_update ...
");

// Later, bind for each
$job_B->bindValue(':id', ...);
// Same value twice...
$job_B->bindValue(':website_insert', $website, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$job_B->bindValue(':website_update', $website, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Is it possible that I was able to use a named parameter marker of the same name twice?

Comment: @bottleboot Don't know without seeing code - it seems unlikely since it is directly stated in the docs that you cannot.

Answer (score 6):

As a general tip, you shouldn't be "duplicating" inserted values when doing an `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. Mysql provides the `VALUES()` function for this purpose, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (:baz)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bar := :baz
```

can be better rewritten as

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (:baz)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bar = VALUES(bar)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`VALUES()` will re-use the value assigned to the specified field in the `VALUES (...)` section automatically, without requiring binding another variable into the query.

Comment: +1 I consistently forget about this because I don't use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` often

Answer (score 2):

The use of VALUES() to refer to the new row and columns is deprecated beginning with MySQL 8.0.20, and is subject to removal in a future version of MySQL.