# PDO INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE inserting and updating only 6 rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using foreach loop to get data and INSERT into database.

When i use INSERT ... ON UPDATE it is inserting only 6 rows instead of 31.

If i use just INSERT without ON UPDATE, it is inserting all 31 records.

Database looks like this
[image]

Code

```
foreach ($data as $key => $object) {
$name = $object->name;
$macd = $object->macd;
$rsi = $object->rsi;
$heikin = $object->heikin;
$atp =  $object->atp;
$ebd = $object->ebd;
$date = $object->date;

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO daily_analyse (name, macd, rsi, heikin, atp, ebd, date) VALUES (:name, :macd, :rsi, :heikin, :atp, :ebd, :date) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), macd = VALUES(macd), rsi = VALUES(rsi), heikin = VALUES(heikin), atp = VALUES(atp), ebd = VALUES(ebd), date = VALUES(date)");

$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':macd', $macd);
$stmt->bindParam(':rsi', $rsi);
$stmt->bindParam(':heikin', $heikin);
$stmt->bindParam(':atp', $atp);
$stmt->bindParam(':ebd', $ebd);
$stmt->bindParam(':date', $date);
$stmt->execute(); 
}
```

I am getting this error

> Error : exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7/13/2018' for key 'date'' in /home/test.php:39 
>       Stack trace: #0 /home/test.php(39): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}

Sample data

```
User1, -9.4709688279058, 65.485783538714, 15.102926302645, 2071.5210433061, -39.057303370785, 7/13/2018
User2, -7.0387293434146, 74.369738650677, 22.950927744359, 2346.1245293301, 16.224382022472, 7/13/2018
User3, -12.262210050659, 65.794347000194, 11.766792820541, 2087.7169870647, -39.007303370786, 7/12/2018
User4, -18.563885914778, 40.972854885722, 1.970264705054, -2486.2857541652, -75.724044943821, 7/13/2018
User5, -9.2538092463374, 66.801519101633, 14.957188794467, 1993.7038310694, -10.75202247191, 7/12/2018
User6, -15.751961165625, 50.113579295874, 12.384504645753, 2253.4898090767, -70.362696629214, 7/13/2018
User7, -29.527566236053, 21.183011205795, -2.7274771575057, -2078.4759312902, -154.75247191011, 7/13/2018
User8, -3.0264511275172, 54.994147779482, 14.876326517899, 2331.1682663662, -32.582359550562, 7/13/2018
User9, -20.750921244733, 59.249132289786, 23.670372635365, 2962.710928428, -91.891797752808, 7/13/2018
User10, -27.932548522575, 38.891513214047, 6.66911663577, -2248.6323934174, -122.47876404494, 7/13/2018
User11, 11.174244482895, 59.805125598132, -1.1108473312506, 1850.8007659455, 59.156629213483, 7/13/2018
User12, 1.2763039433539, 78.985341938355, 46.380098528749, 1866.0820879785, 85.741797752809, 7/12/2018
User13, -12.190747954362, 40.292814821546, -0.10434851940227, -1684.3961859993, -30.296179775281, 7/9/2018
User14, -28.25064775909, 39.279813443065, 25.471390836079, -2123.8553395308, -18.702921348315, 7/13/2018
User15, -2.827259580743, 55.010730092194, 19.287458523068, -1406.9831291156, -0.43696629213491, 7/10/2018
User16, 38.375553401501, 45.453224372335, -30.299834073068, 1705.4531510303, 276.07516853933, 7/11/2018
User17, -44.801920924378, 29.437382210702, -20.391524146904, -2884.5435805497, -271.42382022472, 7/13/2018
User18, 15.656232109745, 38.605958218247, -41.332053270361, -1355.0607008364, 205.70741573034, 7/4/2018
User19, -44.254022779533, 19.151829421512, -26.835155085751, -2587.9411560619, -255.7193258427, 7/12/2018
User20, 2.9727641147826, 29.352899914689, -16.633731345117, -1948.6545928488, NULL, 7/12/2018
User21, 1.1718433594694, 19.683564157951, -25.528676878314, -1899.547504175, -39.080449438202, 7/13/2018
User22, 4.0600834491879, 27.138221463165, -13.363551832987, -1972.3885366358, -7.8215730337072, 7/12/2018
User23, 3.1214979522206, 56.633836476145, -0.68555760015715, -1873.6385494506, -20.035280898876, 7/13/2018
User24, -5.0592893026469, 21.016429549475, -17.33575393937, -1874.2297341504, NULL, 7/12/2018
User25, 0.80284564931117, 40.410740242703, -14.901225176099, -1753.5601686416, -22.829325842696, 7/13/2018
User26, -15.705912374503, 39.709891663578, -16.397693300268, -1926.2009706647, -72.818539325843, 7/13/2018
User27, 10.351871940793, 55.678722919971, -2.0356607222616, 1904.4840650739, 57.554044943819, 7/13/2018
User28, -0.44915732665004, 25.662058472862, -28.277310224057, -1904.2582194672, -36.877303370787, 7/13/2018
User29, -3.205388610008, 39.411367056573, -12.692193718864, -1921.599865055, -47.022359550562, 7/13/2018
User30, NULL, NULL, 446.25092254639, NULL, NULL, 7/13/2018
User31, NULL, NULL, -215.745, NULL, NULL, 7/13/2018
```

And this users are not inserted

```
User20, 2.9727641147826, 29.352899914689, -16.633731345117, -1948.6545928488, NULL, 7/12/2018
User24, -5.0592893026469, 21.016429549475, -17.33575393937, -1874.2297341504, NULL, 7/12/2018
User31, NULL, NULL, -215.745, NULL, NULL, 7/13/2018
```

Comment: Your update syntax is a bit odd...

Comment: @HorusKol In what way is odd ? I checked this topic it must work like this, but not sure why is only inserting only 6 result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028860/on-duplicate-key-update-not-working-in-pdo

Comment: Ah, no worries, I just haven't used the values function in  on...update

Comment: Use these error checking methods if you're not already doing so, to see if it returns anything http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner getting this error "Error : exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7/13/2018' for key 'date'' in /home/test.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /home/test.php(39): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}"

Comment: any linked tables? btw, I wouldn't store dates as text; use a `DATE` type and you'll thank me for it. Why? Because; it's much easier to work / query with. Text based dates are a real headache, believe me. Can you upate your question to contain that error? And also what's looping through that and the input data's origin? That might help others to see what they can come up with. I just can't put my finger on it, sorry.

Comment: also and if you don't have one. Try creating a primary key on an id column that auto increments also. That may be part of the issue here, if you don't already have one that is.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i don't have any linked tables. For date i really don't care right now because i won't use it like date just a visual. I tried already with ID Primary Key Auto Increment, its same.

Comment: I removed date from query and database now it inserting all, i run code again after it inserted all and no problem, i guess problem is in date.

Comment: what about that `foreach`? where's the stuff for that? Can you show us what that is and some sample data going in / already there? It's hard to say what's causing this. Trailing spaces maybe? Man, I don't know.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner updated topic, with sample data, and records that are not inserted.

Comment: better check for empty / NULL values, you have many in there and your db isn't letting you. Some of those inputs to me, seem to not have been filled or radios/checkboxes not checked and no default value. Try using a ternary operator with a default of say "123" or "abc", then see which ones are causing that. I'd start `var_dump()`'ing here and to check your source/html. We need to see the HTML for this also.

Comment: I checked with `var_dump();` outside of loop and inside, i get all 31 results. Table is empty every time before i run a script just to make sure all is inserted, it insert 28 records only, but if i run a script just with INSERT it store all 31 result in database, i don't understand that. By the way, this is json sent from javascript file, i use `$data = json_decode($_POST['data_input']);` before i put data into loop.

Comment: try removing the constraint on not accepting NULL values for the affected column(s). I honestly don't know where to throw myself here. Wish I could help you some more but I can't pinpoint it. I'm going to go and play me some guitar because my head needs a break lol. Cheers man, I really hope you find this ghost of a bug and possibly post your own answer. I'd be happy to upvote it.

Comment: just a closing note here that I forgot asking earlier. I thought of it but forgot to ask. You running this on MySQL or MSSQL / other? I'd add the tag for it also. No need to respond; it's wanting to kick into the discussion room. *ciao*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner MySQL database. Thanks for your time, i hope someone can help with this if i don't find any solution before.

Comment: you're welcome. So try what I suggested and see what that gives. Btw also, that thing about using the right type for your dates? The same thing applies here for what I see as being integers. You're going to have a mess of time in trying to math on that, if and when you have to. If you're new to all this, I'd think this over a little more and read the manuals on mysql.com and tutorials as well as on php.net. Now you mention JSON; now "that" could be a different ballgame here. Post as much as you possibly can, but using minimal data/example for it. This seems to go deeper than known.

Comment: Am I missing something? If duplicate dates are acceptable, amend your date column definition accordingly. Otherwise, don't have duplicate dates.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

After a while, reading many things in comments and searching topics on stackoverflow and google i solved this.

I changed column types, set default values to NULL for numbers only and added new UNIQUE indexes.

Now all works including importing dates, even that before was not possible.

Here is a how my database looks now
[image]

Thank you all guys that helped with this.